# Node.js fs.readfile works infinitly

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I have a problem with a fs.readfile method. I have the following code:

```
fs.readFile(path.join(__static, '/file.json'), function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);

            return;
        }

        authorize(JSON.parse(data));
    });
```

The problem is, it worked fine all the time on my main computer but today I cloned my repo on the laptop and it does not work that well. I always reach the line above readFile occurence on laptop, but most of the times (not always), readFile seems to be working infinitly, it neither logs any errors nor runs authorize method. When I refresh my app and run this again, it reads the file instantly. This seems to me like the reading thread blocks itself for some reason, don't know why. And by the way, .json file I'm reading is 1kB.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do fs.readFile on json files. Just require() the file and it will be available to you as parsed object.

```
let file = require('./file.json');

console.log(file)
```

Comment: This solution worked for the workflow of my app, but still doesn't answer my question. Why readFIle doesn't work always :/ still I vote this answer up and wait for another ones :) thanks

Comment: Maybe encoding issue. Try specifying the encoding fs.readFile(path.join(__static, '/file.json'), 'utf8', function (err, data)

Comment: unfortunetaly not, this doesn't solve the problem :/ I have no idea why this isn't working, even if I had some refreshing or interupting on a master thread, readfile is still an async callback and should finish :/